# How can I make an async function run in the background?

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I can't figure out how to make an async function not block the next line of code/prevent the loop from starting again from the top.

The async function:

```py
async def updateEmbed(self, ctx, obj: discord.Message):

    while self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] == 1:

        mainembed = discord.Embed(title='Current Servers', colour=discord.Colour.purple(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

        result = [[f'{key} | ({len(value)} players)', *value] for key, value in self.bot.scrimmatches[ctx.guild.id].items()]

        for x in result:
            people = []
            for aperson in x[1:]:
                person = self.bot.get_user(aperson)
                people.append(f'{person.mention}\n')

            mainembed.add_field(name=x[0], value=(''.join(people)))

        await obj.edit(embed=mainembed)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

The main command:

```py
            self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] = 0

            async with async_timeout.timeout(length):
                try:
                    while True:
                        msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
                        await tryRemoveUser(self, ctx, user=msg.author)
                        try:
                            self.bot.scrimmatches[msg.guild.id][((msg.content).upper())].append(msg.author.id)
                        except:
                            self.bot.scrimmatches[msg.guild.id] = ((msg.content).upper())
                        if self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] == 0:
                            self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] = 1
                            await updateEmbed(self, ctx, obj=history)
                except:
                    pass
```

On the main command, I want the while True loop to start again, however the loop gets stuck in the while loop on the updateEmbed function, so it stops reading the messages as the loop does not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with that nasty code but your `updateEmbed` method will never stop until `while self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] == 1:` is true.

Look at this code you wrote:

```
if self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] == 0:
    self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] = 1
    await updateEmbed(self, ctx, obj=history)
```

First you set `self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id]` to 1 and then you call `await updateEmbed(self, ctx, obj=history)` which will never end because it has infinite loop:

```
while self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id] == 1:
```

Which is always going to be true thus loop forever because you never change `self.bot.toggle[ctx.guild.id]` to some other value.

Instead of doing some nasty infinite loops head over to [Discord.Py rewrite API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#api-reference) and use [events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#event-reference)